# Print string to a java.io.Console object

Tags: java, printing, console

I'm making a multi-player game where each player has their own input/output console on the screen. I'm having a bit of trouble trying to do this. I don't want every player to see other player's in/outputs.

To use an analogy, I want to do something like `playerOneConsole.out.println("Player One String");`, instead of `System.out.println("Player One String");` where everyone can see player one's stuff.

After reading some documentation, I've tried this, but it does not work as intended as it throws a NullPointerException:

```
public class Player {

    String myName;
    Console myConsole;

    public Player(String name) {
        myName = name;
        myConsole = System.console();
    }


    public void takeTurn(String playerOptions){
        myConsole.writer().print(playerOptions); //This is not right.
    }
}
```

I want `playerOptions` to print exclusively to that player's console, not the `System` console.

By the way, I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: So presumably `myConsole` is `null`, because you're running in an environment where `System.console()` returns `null`, e.g. in Eclipse?

Comment: Since there are multiple consoles, they must be implemented somehow, and there must be a way of addressing them separately.  On a Linux/Unix system I guess they would ultimately be addressed with separate file handles whether or not implemented in application software, OS software or OS hardware.   Which is it?  If in application software is it 3rd party of something of your own design?  If its 3rd party, take a look in the API for a solution.

Comment: Maybe you could use pseudo terminals (pty) implemented in Java using Pty4J which provides read/write access but requires running some kind of shell in each pty.  It supports Linux, OSX and Windows platforms and is available at https://github.com/traff/pty4j.

Answer (score 6):

When using `java.io.Console`, you must execute the Java app from a console e.g. Windows CMD or Linux Terminal. Most IDEs won't execute Java through a console, so `System#console` returns `null`.

By the way, this code:

```
myConsole.writer().print(playerOptions); //This is not right.
```

It's right indeed :)

Comment: I've managed to Build my application and run it in Windows command prompt. It runs but simply ignores the line calling `myConsole.writer().print(playerOptions);`. I should be expecting a new cmd window to open, right?

 If I run command prompt as administrator, I get this error:
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: Are you sure the line is executed and it's not empty?